# Google sheet formula to access a column from references to multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a few sheets in a Google spreadsheet with column-A having dates. I want to count the number of cells in column L of each sheet with date less than today. The names of sheets to be lookedup are mentioned in the last sheet's A1 to A20. I tried several methods to find the right formula, but none worked.
The most suggested formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&A1:A20&"'!A:A"), "<"&TODAY()))
```

But this is not working. The values are all zero.
If I try individual sheets, like below, it works.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A:A"), "<"&TODAY()) + COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!A:A"), "<"&TODAY()) + .....
```

I want to avoid adding individual sums as it makes the formula very big and if I have to add one new sheet, then I need to change a lot of code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try with:*

```js
=sum(map(tocol(A1:A20,1),lambda(Σ,countif(indirect(Σ&"!A:A"),"<"&today()))))
```